# Using hibernate filters inside of a formula: error executing query with hql

Tags: hibernate, filter, hql

I have the following problem with a query I try to execute with Hibernate. 
SqlServer gives me the following exception:

```
sqlserverexception the value is not set for the parameter number XX
```

where XX is a number changing according to the number of other filters in the query.

I have a mapping file which represent the object I'm trying to retrieve from the db mapped as follows:

```
<hibernate-mapping auto-import="false">
<class name="Employee" table="e2_per_dipendenti" batch-size="250">
    <id name="id" column="id" >
        <generator class="guid"/>
    </id>

...other fields...

<many-to-one name="currentSegment" lazy="false"
                formula="(select sd.fk_e0_prof_nodo from e1_tur_stati_dip sd 
              where sd.dt_efficacia &lt;=:filtroStatoOperativo.dataRif 
              )"/>  

<filter-def name="filtroStatoOperativo">
    <filter-param name="dataRif"  type="calendar"/>
</filter-def>
```

You can see that the filter is used in the formula inside the many-to-one.

Then I try to make a query like this, enabling the filter and setting the value for it:

```
Session session = sessionManager.getFilteredSession(FilterType.NODO);
String sql = "from " + Employee.class.getName() + " dip";

GregorianCalendar oggi = GeneralUtil.getDate(new GregorianCalendar());
        Filter f = session.enableFilter("filtroStatoOperativo");
        f.setParameter("dataRif", oggi);

Query query = session.createQuery(sql);
List<Employee> result = (List<Employee>)query.list();
```

Maybe what I'm doing wrong is trying to use a query with hql instead of a one using criteria? 
(since the query is a big one I didn't try to translate it with Criteria still)

**EDIT: I tried using Criteria instead of hql in a mockup query (on the same mapped bean) and the trick works. So I guess it's a matter of filters not working as I thought using HQL. Can you support my guess with some official documentation?**

thanks